# Mapping IP addresses to networks of an organization

Tags: python, ip, cidr

I have a bunch of ip addresses (millions of them) and I want to map these ip addresses to organizations (only IPv4).

Organizations can possess their own networks or blocks of ip addresses such as 103.246.199.0/24 (CIDR), where the network starts with 103.246.199.000 and ends with 103.246.199.255.

However, one organization can have multiple networks and I am searching for an fast way to map IP addresses to a specific organization.

Assuming I have these IP addresses

`ip_addresses = ["99.128.102.23", "103.246.199.233", "199.253.242.44", "28.128.75.10"]`

and one organization has the following networks

`org_networks = ["103.246.199.0/24", "199.253.242.0/24", "170.148.64.0/21"]`.

Does anybody know a fast way of checking whether the ip addresses are in the organization's network?

Comment: so you want to check if some ip in org_networks with CIDR matches the one with those you specified in ip addresses. There are quite a lot of ways to achieve them, but you have not specified whether it is required to be run at runtime or processed as batch operation once only, essentailly converting all ip adresses at once and save a copy in db or some other format.

Comment: The method is only for analysis purposes, so it is not required to be run at runtime. In particular I am trying to match ip addresses of the SEC EDGAR Logfile dataset (https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/edgar-log-file-data-set.html) to organizations. These ip addreses are anonymized in the last octett of the ip address (e.g. 123.234.123.xxx).

A method that converts the addresses all at once  and saves a copy or something in a db sounds interesting!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import ipaddress

ipinhand = ["99.128.102.23", "103.246.199.233", "199.253.242.44", "28.128.75.10"]
ipsets = set()

#initially converting inhand ip's to sets if ipaddress objects
for element in ipinhand:
  ipsets.add(ipaddress.ip_address(element))

org_networks = ["103.246.199.0/24", "199.253.242.0/24", "170.148.64.0/21"]

#loading the org_networks list into pandas df
df = pd.DataFrame(org_networks,columns =['org_networks'])

def crosscheck(ipwithcidr):
 newpool = ipaddress.ip_network(ipwithcidr)
 return not ipsets.isdisjoint(newpool)


df["checks"] = df.org_networks.apply(crosscheck)

print(df)
```

Output

```
       org_networks  checks
0  103.246.199.0/24    True
1  199.253.242.0/24    True
2   170.148.64.0/21   False
```

I have modified and incorporated ipaddress library now.

Check if suits your need

Comment: I'd rather use `ipaddress` library.

Comment: Thanks! The model is quite smart but I think that taking only the first three value sets of an ip address into consideration is not the right way. 
E.g. CIDR network `170.148.64.0/21` has the range from `170.148.64.0` to `170.148.71.255`. 

`ipaddress` library sounds helpful, I am also trying to work with the `ipcalc` package.

Comment: yeah, i was naive; but now amended my initial suggestion, check it out

Comment: i hope it is compliant with CIDR conversions now @JimKnopf.

Comment: it is a very good start for my current task and also compliant with CIDR conversion, thanks a lot @PIngu